# Auth0 Login Flow: add Username to idToken

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, auth0

I've spent at least 2 hours searching for this info and I can't believe it's so hard to find.
I want to know how to add `username` to the idToken issued by calling /oauth/token.
I want to have username inside the object that comes from decoding the token, alongside nickname, email, email_verified and other standard claims.
[image]

I tried with a custom rule which seems to allow you to add custom claims to the idToken but it doesn't work:

```
/**
* Handler that will be called during the execution of a PostLogin flow.
*
* @param {Event} event - Details about the user and the context in which they are logging in.
* @param {PostLoginAPI} api - Interface whose methods can be used to change the behavior of the login.
*/
exports.onExecutePostLogin = async (event, api) => {
  api.idToken.setCustomClaim("username", event.user.username);
  api.accessToken.setCustomClaim("username", event.user.username);
};
```

I'm not very keen on oauth and authentication in general, but how can it be so hard to do such a simple thing?!!